# Domain user access to non domain share and vice versa

Tags: permissions, active-directory, share, windows-server-2008, administration

I have two servers:
 - ServerA in domain LLOP
 - ServerB out of domain

On both I have a shares:

- \ServerA\shared
- \ServerB\shared

I am trying to make both shares accessible with domain user "TechAcc" there is no problem with accessing Server A. From the last patch my ServerB is not accessible anymore (I have been using "bug" with the same local administrator user name as domain one).

I don't want to enable guest logins on any machine, I know it would fix the problem but it is unsecure.

What I have tried so far:

- Different user's permissions
- Allow Cross-Forest User Policy
- Anonymous access

I am out of options right now :(
Is there any way to tell what credential are used for connection to the share?

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys after 2-3h of blind configuration I have found an solution.
You have to enable "Allow Cross-Forest User Policy" and add explicite connection credential via Credential Manager.